# Comparing data without disclosing it

Tags: security, cryptography, dataset

Two companies A and B want to compare their respective customer bases and figure out the overlap.

Obviously, they can't exchange their customer base. So they need to come up with a process to compare their listing without disclosing any information beside the intersection of both (which defies the whole idea of comparing).

Basically, if I'm a customer of A (identified by my email) and also a customer of B. They both should be able to know after the comparison. However, if I'm only a customer of A, B should NOT be able to identify me, and vice-versa.

Moreover, neither A nor B have the least incentive to disclose any qualitative information about their datasets, such as how many customers  they have, or their respective rate of duplication, "incorrectness", etc... The ideal solution should convey information about the intersection, period.

The obvious technical solution seems to hash the identifiers before sending them to the other parties. Both parties can compare with their own after hashing using the exact same method. They can find if an identifier matches but they won't be able to identify the others. However both A and B would know the exact size of each other's dataset. All of this assuming that hashing is not reversible. What else could to be done to solve the problem following that path?

The other solution that is being considered is to find a trusted third party that receives both dataset either plain or hashed, does the comparison and send the intersection to both A and B. I don't know where to find such a service.

Comment: Could A add a number of a fake email addresses before hashing which have been confirmed not to be in existence? If there is a unique identifier beside email, could fake versions of that unique identifier be created which no real customer would own? That way A could hide its number while still allowing matches to be found.

Comment: Thanks @TonyRuth, introducing randomness does definitely help. For the entropy to be high enough, each of the parties need a fairly high amount of random data. Even though, each of the parties can keep each other's database forever and salvage some of the data. eg. If both know that email addresses were used, a dictionary attack could work on the hashes. I was wondering if there was a method to solve the problem in a kind of "zero trust" configuration.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not directly related to programming. [crypto.se] or even [security.se] are much better suited for this type of question.

Answer (score 1):

A trusted third party would be the way to go here.

The hashing solution is not feasible. To be able to compare the hashes, both A and B would have to use the same hashing algorithm. If both create hashes for all of their customer email addresses, and A then shares the hash of a shared user with B, B can reference the hash to the plaintext email address.

Salts and other such techniques also don't help since, once again, both parties would need to use the same salts to make the hashes comparable.

Lastly, even when A shares the hash of a customer that B does not have, it would be comparatively easy to reverse the hash. For example, B could hash a list of all potential customers and check against it. (This wouldn't reverse every address, but it would still be too large a business risk.)

If a fully trusted 3rd party can't be found, a hybrid approach might work best:
Hash all email addresses, send *only* the hashes to the 3rd party and have it check which ones overlap.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following ways,

1. Add some fake details, which will surely increase the data and could also be reversible at some level
2. Use the technique such as if my email id is stackoverflow@example.com then each parties can change it to some predefined methods like,

   - stackoverflow@example.com becomes s#a#k#v#r#l#w@e#a#p#e.c#m
   - In addition to that, you can also add some checksum of "stackoverflow@example.com" using predefined methods, like ASCII value of characters. However, there is also possibility of dictionary attack or such scenario to retrieve the valid email ids but there will be some level of security. or you can also apply such logic as per your requirement to make it complex.
3. Trusted third-party as you already mentioned.